# How do you enable VS2013 c++ compiler functionality?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c++11

So I'm pretty stumped here. I have a Library "A" that I wrote in C++ with VS2013, and can successfully include and build it within project "X".

Project "X" is an MFC app also developed in VS2013, and its `Platform Toolset` value is set to `VS2013`. It happens to be a Win32 application.

I now have to include the library in a different project "Y" (which was a VS2010 project, but I (believe I) converted it using VS to 2013).

Project "Y" is NOT an MFC app, instead a .dll, and its `Platform Toolset` value is also set to `VS2013`. It is an x64 application.

However, when I try to build "Y", I get tons of compiler errors, mostly because the library uses C++11 features, and apparently VS isn't allowing it. The errors are mostly vector bracket-initialization syntax problems. E.G. `non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list`. But in addition, it also can't find symbols for `strtoll` and `report_rangecheckfailure`.

But I don't understand. To my knowledge, VS2013 should support these features, and it appears to in my other projects. What could be the issue here? Is there something else I need to do to use the 2013 compiler?

**Edit**
Just to be extra clear, it's assignments like this that give the aggregate compiler message:

```
std::vector<std::string> paramVector = { "username", "time", "hours", "udata" };
```

Comment: I would ensure you are using VS2013 update 4 as that fixed a number of problems with initialiser lists. I use patterns like the one you have above all the time with no problems in it.

Comment: I'm on update 5, so I should be alright. This is extremely odd, especially since, like I said, this works properly on a different project, which uses the same version of VS.

Comment: Are you trying to have a win32 (32-bit) application use a x64 library (64-bit)?

Comment: @Wilbert, No, "Y" is set to an x64 .dll, and is using 64 bit libraries (libcurl and openssl). I built both of those libraries myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it also can't find symbols for strtoll and report_rangecheckfailure

Strongest hint towards the underlying problem, those would be linker errors.  So one hard fact is evident: you are not linking the VS2013 C runtime library.  These symbols exist in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\libmsvcrt.lib and libcmt.lib but not in earlier versions, like the VS2010 version.

From there it is but a very short hop to explain the "non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list" error.  Clearly you are also not including the appropriate VS2013 `<vector>` include file.  Required to get that vector assignment to compile.  Again, including the VS2010 version of it explains that error.

Rock-hard fact: your Y project is not configured correctly.

Getting it wrong *both* for the compiler and the linker does point squarely at the toolset target setting, even though you think it is correct.  A standard mistake would be to change the setting for the Debug configuration but forgetting to also do it for the Release configuration.  Having the Project > Properties > VC++ Directories set wrong would be another way.  The compiler's /showIncludes and the linker's /verbose options give you enough feedback to verify your assumptions.  If you're absolutely desperate then recreate the Y project.

Comment: Ah, the VC++ directories were the problem! Thanks so much, I didn't notice they were wrong since they were set as macros. The `/showIncludes` option was very handy.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible reasons is that C++11 is partially supported by VS2013, see this table for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

And anyway, it's better to show an example of the errors you got so far.

Comment: That page does claim that initalizer lists are available in 2013. Also, I did give an example of my most common error. The rest of the errors are pretty much related to that initialization failing.

Comment: Question: does it compile if you make it without "=" sign: std::vector<std::string> paramVector{ "username", "time", "hours", "udata" };

Comment: No, but I get a different error: `error C2601: 'paramVector' : local function definitions are illegal`

Comment: Then, could you try to explicitly include this header? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn454608.aspx